# How to make ajv validation using postman return key/value in error message

Tags: json, validation, postman

## Background

I'm using [ajv with postman](https://medium.com/tomincode/validating-json-with-ajv-14bcddd9f24c) for json schema validation. It works well, however it only gives me a single fail/pass result for an entire schema validation, rather than the exact failing key/value pair:

```
var Ajv = require('ajv'),
    ajv = new Ajv({logger: console}),
    schema = {
        "properties": {
                "data" : {
                     "type": "object",
                     "properties" : {
                            "categories" : {
                                   "type": "array",
                                   "items" : [
                                           {"type": "object",
                                            "properties" : {
                                                    "id": {"type": "number"},
                                                    "ref": {"type": ['null', 'string']},
                                                    "parent_id": {"type": ['null', 'number']},
                                                    "image": {"type": ['null', 'string']},
         ...

  pm.test('Schema is valid', function() {
    var data = pm.response.json()['data'];
    pm.expect(ajv.validate(schema, {data: data})).to.be.true;

});
```

[image]

## Question

How can I make avj/postman return the exact wrong key/pair validation?

## update

For this to work, the avj object must be declared like so:

```
var Ajv = require('ajv'),
ajv = new Ajv({logger: console,
            allErrors: true,
            verbose: true
}),
```

Comment: There is an `errors` object that holds the information - `pm.expect(ajv.validate(accessSchema, pm.response.json()), JSON.stringify(ajv.errors[0].message)).to.be.true;` Not sure of the answer but something is in there to expose that.

Comment: perfect! if you put your comment as an answer i'll mark it as correct

Comment: Will do, I'd be interested to see how you use it. Any links to any write-ups would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the `ajv.errors` object, that holds the information.

https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv#validation-errors

For example, by adding something like this to the `pm.expect()` statement, it should show the message part of the error in the Postman Tests Results:

```
pm.expect(ajv.validate(ajv.validate(schema, {data: data}), JSON.stringify(ajv.errors[0].message)).to.be.true;
```

That's only going to show the first object in the array so you'd need to capture this in a different way if you wanted to iterate through that data.

Comment: better output is `JSON.stringify(ajv.errors[0])` - it provides more details than filed message

Comment: For sure, I just picked the one that would tell you the actual problem 

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to print in the console the error message is by adding a an extra parameter to validate().
First declare a "printErrors" function at the beginning of your Postman script tests:

```
function printErrors(ajv){
    if(ajv.errors !== null){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(ajv.errors[0]));    
    }
}
```

Then add the a call to validate, like this:

```
var ajv = new Ajv({logger: console,
        allErrors: true,
        verbose: true
}),
yourData = {"your Data"}
yourSchema = {"your schema"};
pm.test('Schema is valid', function() {
    pm.expect(ajv.validate(schema, yourData), printErrors(ajv)).to.be.true;
});
```

You will see the log in the console box. To open it you have to click on the console button, the third one starting from the left. [image]